# SQL sum columns aggregate by others "dislocated" columns

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregation

I would be very grateful if you could help me with this problem.

I have this results of a Oracle SQL query, are about a night shift schedule.

start_day_hours are the total worked hours between the  shift start_date and the midnight.
end_day_hours are the total worked hours between the midnight en the end of the shift.

```
start            midnight          end               start_day_hours      end_day_hours
02/10/17 21:33  02/10/17 23:59   03/10/17 00:42       2,43                0,71
03/10/17 21:34  03/10/17 23:59   04/10/17 00:19       2,42                0,32
04/10/17 21:59  04/10/17 23:59   05/10/17 55:36       2,00                0,92
16/10/17 21:59  16/10/17 23:59   17/10/17 00:01       2,00                0,01
18/10/17 22:50  18/10/17 23:59   19/10/17 00:25       1,16                0,42
19/10/17 22:19  19/10/17 23:59   20/10/17 01:00       1,67                1,01
```

I need the sum of start_day_hours and end_day_hours by day, something like:

```
  day         total_hours
02/10/17         2,43    (2,43)
03/10/17         3,13    (0.71+2,42)
04/10/17         2,32    (0.32+2.00)
05/10/17         0,92    (0,92)
16/10/17         2,00    (2,00)
17/10/17         0,01    (0,01)
18/10/17         1,16    (1,16)
19/10/17         2,51    (0.42+1.67)
20/10/17         1,01    (1,01)
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: _Columns_, not _fields_.

Comment: Thanks!, what a mistake!

Comment: Midnight is not at `23:59` - you are putting a minute onto the start of each day that should be at the end of the previous day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/29492/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE shift (
  "start" DATE,
  "end"   DATE
);

INSERT INTO shift
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-10-02 21:33:00',  TIMESTAMP '2017-10-03 00:42:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-10-03 21:34:00',  TIMESTAMP '2017-10-04 00:19:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-10-04 21:59:00',  TIMESTAMP '2017-10-05 00:55:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-10-16 21:59:00',  TIMESTAMP '2017-10-17 00:01:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-10-18 22:50:00',  TIMESTAMP '2017-10-19 00:25:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-10-19 22:19:00',  TIMESTAMP '2017-10-20 01:00:00' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

Use a row generator to get each day between the earliest `start` and the latest `end` and then join it to the original table when the day overlaps the shift and aggregate those overlaps:

```
WITH days ( dt ) AS (
  SELECT min_dt + LEVEL - 1
  FROM   (
    SELECT TRUNC( MIN( "start" ) ) AS min_dt,
           TRUNC( MAX( "end" ) )   AS max_dt
    FROM   shift
  )
  CONNECT BY min_dt + LEVEL - 1 <= max_dt
)
SELECT dt,
       SUM(
         LEAST( "end", dt + INTERVAL '1' DAY )
         - GREATEST( "start", dt )
       ) * 24 AS hours_worked
FROM   shift s
       INNER JOIN days d
       ON (    s."start" < d.dt + INTERVAL '1' DAY
           AND s."end"   > d.dt )
GROUP BY dt
ORDER BY dt
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/29492/4/0)**:

```
|                   DT |         HOURS_WORKED |
|----------------------|----------------------|
| 2017-10-02T00:00:00Z |                 2.45 |
| 2017-10-03T00:00:00Z |   3.1333333333333333 |
| 2017-10-04T00:00:00Z |   2.3333333333333335 |
| 2017-10-05T00:00:00Z |   0.9166666666666666 |
| 2017-10-16T00:00:00Z |   2.0166666666666666 |
| 2017-10-17T00:00:00Z | 0.016666666666666666 |
| 2017-10-18T00:00:00Z |   1.1666666666666667 |
| 2017-10-19T00:00:00Z |                  2.1 |
| 2017-10-20T00:00:00Z |                    1 |
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @MT0

Answer (score 0):

One simple way could be to union`start/end date` into 1 column and `start_hours/end_hours` into other column, `trunc` `date` column, `group by` date and calculate `sum` of `hours` column as below.

```
SELECT date1 AS DAY,
       sum(hours) AS total_hours
FROM
  (SELECT trunc(start1) AS date1,
          start_day_hours AS hours
   FROM t1
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT trunc(end1),
          end_day_hours
   FROM t1 ) t
GROUP BY date1
ORDER BY date1;
```

**Result:**

```
DAY                   TOTAL_HOURS
---------------------------------
02.10.2017 00:00:00   2,43
03.10.2017 00:00:00   3,13
04.10.2017 00:00:00   2,32
05.10.2017 00:00:00   0,92
16.10.2017 00:00:00   2
17.10.2017 00:00:00   0,01
18.10.2017 00:00:00   1,16
19.10.2017 00:00:00   2,09
20.10.2017 00:00:00   1,01
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/QNHOJ54334)**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help @MT0. Finally I have done this:

```
SELECT dt,
   NVL(SUM(
     LEAST( SIXTY, dt + INTERVAL '1' DAY )
     - GREATEST( ZERO, dt )
   ) * 24, 0.0) AS hours_worked
FROM shitf s
   RIGHT JOIN 
(SELECT TO_DATE('2017-10-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD  HH24:MI:SS')+LEVEL-1 AS dt
FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('2017-10-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD  HH24:MI:SS')),'DD')) d
ON (s.ZERO < d.dt + INTERVAL '1' DAY
       AND s.SIXTY   > d.dt )
GROUP dt
ORDER dt
```

Comment: And thanks to everyone for devoting a little of their time!!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT T1.START_DATE,nvl(T1.START_DAY_HOURS,0) + nvl(T2.END_DAY_HOURS,0) TOTAL_HOURS
FROM 
(SELECT TRUNC(START) START_DATE,sum(nvl(START_DAY_HOURS,0)) START_DAY_HOURS  FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY TRUNC(START)) T1

LEFT JOIN (SELECT TRUNC(END) END_DATE,SUM(nvl(END_DAY_HOURS,0)) END_DAY_HOURS FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY TRUNC(END)) T2
ON T1.START_DATE = T2.END_DATE
```

Comment: This will not aggregate the values if there are more than 2 shifts per day and it looks like it will miss the last row (when there is only the end of the shift on that day).

Comment: Its not just the last row it will miss - it will miss every day where there is an end date without a corresponding start date. Also, when there is a start date with no corresponding end date then the total hours will be `NULL`.

Comment: Not to be offensive but I m not trying to spoon feed developers with my SQL. Just trying to show them the direction here where they could investigate on their own. However changed the SQL on your humble request.Thanks.

Comment: There is a difference between not spoon feeding them and giving them SQL that doesn't work against the requirements. [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a0d9bd/3) - it does not show `2017-10-05` or `2017-10-20` and the values for `2017-10-02`, `2017-10-16` and `2017-10-18` are `NULL`.

Comment: You are still missing the days when there is an end date and no start date. Try a `FULL OUTER JOIN` and `NVL` or `COALESCE` on the start date. [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a0d9bd/9)